# how to make a div wrapped in a flex container such that it allows other element to be in same row using html css?

Tags: html, css

Hi below is the html code,

```css
.wrapper {
    min-width: 0%;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 21px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.iconwrapper {
    min-width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iconwrapper">
        <svg/>
    </div>
    <span>sometext</span>
<div>
```

now for some reason the div with class iconwrapper takes up complete space in the div and span appears in the next row or below in wrapper div.

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: display:flex is missing to make wrapper a flex container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `display: flex;` property to `.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {
  ...
  
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the snippet. Like this you can provide.

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.iconwrapper {
    min-width:0;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iconwrapper">
        <svg/>
    </div>
    <span>sometext</span>
<div>
```

Comment: dispaly:flex to wrapper alone did it thanks :)